# flow: transforming union type of multiple strings into new type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, types, flowtype

Say I have this type:

`export type VerificationStatus =
  | 'TRIAL_DEPOSIT_PENDING'
  | 'TRIAL_DEPOSIT_REQUIRED'
  | 'TRIAL_DEPOSIT_EXPIRED'
  | 'TRIAL_DEPOSIT_VERIFICATION_FAILED'
  | 'TRIAL_DEPOSIT_REINITIATE'
  | 'VERIFIED';`

And I have a hash map that might look something like:

`verificationStatus: { trial_deposit_expired: 'Sorry, trial deposits have expired.' },`

etc, where the name of each key value pair should be one of the union above, transformed to lowercase. How to make this into a type `VerificationMapKey`, so I can do: `const verificationStatus: {[name: VerificationMapKey]: string}`?

In other words, `VerificationMapKey` is the return type of a function that iterates over all the possible values of VerificationStatus and turns them lowercase.

Comment: Not possible with flow. The question is why do you need this?

Comment: because I don't  want to type two  enum sets that just differ by case.

Comment: You could just define single object `const verificationStatus = {trial_deposit_expired: '...', ...otherKeys}` and get keys union from it `$Keys<typeof verificationStatus>`

Comment: @AlekseyL won't each of `Keys<typeof verificationStatus>` just be `string`?

Comment: Yeah, that would be a union of keys (that's what you're doing manually here `export type VerificationStatus ...`)

Comment: I want the type to be a union of string literals, the actual values. Not just `string`

Comment: You'll probably need to declare the lowercase versions to get this to work, and you should probably add more context around what you're doing.

Comment: As I said before, it will be union of keys(string literals), not just `string`

Comment: Have you found a solution? The accepted answer is not a solution

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simple as:

```
const VerificationStatuses = ['TRIAL_DEPOSIT_PENDING',
  'TRIAL_DEPOSIT_REQUIRED',
  'TRIAL_DEPOSIT_EXPIRED',
  'TRIAL_DEPOSIT_VERIFICATION_FAILED',
  'TRIAL_DEPOSIT_REINITIATE',
  'VERIFIED'];

const VerificationStausMessagesKey = VerificationStatuses.forEach(status => status.toLowerCase());

export type VerificationStatus = $Keys<typeof VerificationStatuses>;
export type VerificationStausMessageKey = $Keys<typeof VerificationStausMessagesKey>;
```

Comment: Simple, but not working  [try](https://flow.org/try/#0MYewdgzgLgBAagUwE4EsBmLgEMovAZShwFcIEIYBeGAbQHIAVAJQEkBBAGQH0ARAUQAKAeXwsGXAXwByPFlIDidADQAoGDEatOvQSLFcmfAIoBVFoZ7K1G5u279ho8XwAaA830ur1muzsf6cHysAGIsAMJsDCxCUlwhbCwcnlY+ttoOeuKGcmLsDHypGkGhLCkAugDcKiqgkLCIqBjYuAREpACy5BBYAObkANIIAJ5U8MjomDh4YIQkZBAAdGggSHxYwAAWABTQ81QAfDB7UKSLUCAcIADuyOFYZNsAlE-VKlDDAA4I401TrbMiKcKNQACRDYYQAA8H2+IDQv0mLRmc2B5AO1VhP0aSOmbSwnW6fQQELG4JG0Kx8MRzTxgIJEC6EB6-QgEIxNQANghYABrEYALhp-xR7UZRP6pOodCgqCwnK4ABMEJ8QBAUFAuN8wIqUGBenRKkA)

Comment: Try the link above